# Getting a Null Pointer Exception error while Converting Android Tablelayout to Bitmap?

Tags: bitmap, nullpointerexception

I want to get the screenshot of tableview and convert it into a bitmap image to share it with others.
Here is my getscreen() function.

```
private File getScreen() {

    View view = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());// *I am getting error here*

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myPath = new File(extr, "Schedule.png");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 20, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b,
                "Screen", "screen");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myPath;

}
```

I am getting error for following situation:

1) The TableLayout  exceeds the screen size.

When the tablelayout is well within the screen size, I am getting perfect bitmap image.

I have searched online , and tried CreateScaledBitmap.. And other options also.. But none worked.

---

#### Solution

```
  Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null) 
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else 
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: I found the answer Myself Again:-)

Comment: I found that the error was with the emulator and not the code.. So I deleted my emulator and created a new one ...

Comment: My code is not working again ... plzz help someone... Getting the same error again..

Comment: I searched A lot on StackOverflow and My problem is Solved... I wonder why no one has ever replied me . Even I wanted to help someone by my code and stackoverflow does not allow me to post answer . I wud have helped that guy..Any ways PLease see my Edited Post above for the Solution.